# Live Data is not updating ViewModel

Tags: android, retrofit, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

I am observing my viewmodel in an `Activity`:

```
private void setupViewModel() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mSortCategory = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sort_key), getString(R.string.pref_sort_popular));
    MainViewModelFactory factory = new MainViewModelFactory(mSortCategory);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MainViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getResponse().observe(this, new Observer<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(MovieResponse movieResponse) {
            mMovieAdapter.setData(movieResponse.getResults());
            mCurrentPage = movieResponse.getPage();
            mTotalPages = movieResponse.getTotalPages();
            Log.d(TAG, "setupviewmodel: " + movieResponse.getResults().get(0).getOriginalTitle());
        }
    });
```

and here is my VM:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> mMoviesResponseLiveData;

public MainViewModel(String category) {
    mMoviesResponseLiveData = Repository.getInstance().loadMoviesFromApi(category, 1);
}

public void loadMovies(String category, int currentPage) {
    mMoviesResponseLiveData = Repository.getInstance().loadMoviesFromApi(category, currentPage);
}

public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getResponse() {
    return mMoviesResponseLiveData;
}
```

and here I make a call to `retrofit`:

```
 public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> loadMoviesFromApi(String sort, int page) {
    final MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    Call<MovieResponse> call = mApiService.getMoviesResponse(sort, BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY, page);
    Log.d(TAG, "loadMoviesFromApi: " + call.request().url().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                data.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

As I understand new data should be asynchronously loaded by calling a method from activity on `Viewmodel` :

```
private void updateUI() {
    mViewModel.loadMovies(mSortCategory, mCurrentPage);
}
```

I receive data from `retrofit`. but for some reason Livedata is not being observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observer isn't notified because of this method:

```
public void loadMovies(String category, int currentPage) {
    mMoviesResponseLiveData = Repository.getInstance().loadMoviesFromApi(category, currentPage);
}
```

`loadMoviesFromApi` returns a new instance of `LiveData` so the LiveData returned from `getResponse` is no longer referenced by your viewModel. If you want your observer to be notified you should return the ViewModel from method `loadMovies` and observe it or invoke `mMoviesResponseLiveData.postValue(responseFromRetrofit)`

Comment: Thanks. So now I made a field in Repository and set data to it instead. The first Live data instance returned when ViewModel is created gets observed.